# How to implement autoselect using Altair, ipywidgets and pandas

Tags: pandas, altair

This is a bit of code that I'm trying to tidying up that I realised doesn't function properly.

It's a relatively large dataset so my initial approach was to subset the data using a filter that I could plug into a widget. It works and it is then possible to select a letter but if I wanted to select say "Leon", "Rachel" or "Michael" it resets to the top first letter filter.

Is it easier to just have an autoselect widget that will autocomplete on the first letter and allow me to select what I want?

```
# Function to update name options based on the selected first letter
def update_name_options(change):
    new_options = sorted(df[df['first_letter'] == change['new']]['Name'].unique().tolist())
    names_widget.options = new_options

# Function to plot data based on parameters
def plot_data(first_letter=None, names=None, gender=None, measure='Rank'):
    # Filter data based on parameters
    filtered_data = df.copy()
    if first_letter:
        filtered_data = filtered_data[filtered_data['first_letter'] == first_letter]
    if names:
        filtered_data = filtered_data[filtered_data['Name'].isin(names)]
    if gender:
        filtered_data = filtered_data[filtered_data['Gender'].isin(gender)]
    if measure:
        filtered_data = filtered_data[filtered_data['Measure'] == measure]

    # Create the plot
    plot = alt.Chart(filtered_data).mark_line(point=True).encode(
        x=alt.X('Year:O'),
        y=alt.Y('mean(Value):Q', sort='descending'),
        color=alt.Color('Gender:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['boy', 'girl'], range=['blue', 'pink'])),
        tooltip=['Name', 'Gender', 'Value', 'Measure', 'Year']
    ).interactive()

    return plot

# Interactive widgets
first_letter_widget = widgets.Dropdown(options=[None] + sorted(df['first_letter'].unique().tolist()), description='First Letter:', disabled=False)
first_letter_widget.observe(update_name_options, names='value')

names_widget = widgets.SelectMultiple(options=sorted(df['Name'].unique().tolist()), description='Names:', disabled=False)
gender_widget = widgets.SelectMultiple(options=['boy', 'girl'], description='Gender:', disabled=False)
measure_widget = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Rank', 'Count'], description='Measure:', disabled=False)

interact(plot_data, first_letter=first_letter_widget, names=names_widget, gender=gender_widget, measure=measure_widget);
```